# Use of 'auto [...] 'before deduction of 'auto' with recursive, concept-based function template

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I wanted to create a `deep_flatten` function template that would produce a `range` of elements that are deeply `join`ed. For example, if we take into account only nested `std::vector`s, I can have:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_vector : public std::false_type { };

template <typename T, typename A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : public std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
auto deepFlatten(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vec) {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    if constexpr (is_vector<T>::value) {
        auto range = vec | views::join;
        return deepFlatten(std::vector(range.begin(), range.end()));
    } else {
        auto range = vec | views::join;
        return std::vector(range.begin(), range.end());
    }
}
```

This enables me to do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> nested_vectors = {
        {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}},
        {{7},       {8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}},
        {{13}}
};

std::ranges::copy(
        deep_flatten(nested_vectors),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
);
```

which prints into the console the following text, as expected:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
> ```

**But**, I don't like this solution that much. Not only it's inefficient (creating a number of temporary vectors), but it also works only with `std::vector`s. I figured that I could use some more of [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) magic and use `std::ranges::range` concept:

```
namespace rng {
    template <std::ranges::range Rng>
    auto deep_flatten(Rng&& rng) {
        using namespace std::ranges;

        if constexpr (range<Rng>) {
            return deep_flatten(rng | views::join);
        } else {
            return rng | views::join;
        }
    }
}
```

This seemed to me pretty straightforward - we have a `std::ranges::range` and we inspect it's value type. Depending on whether it's a nested range, we recurse or simply return `join`ed elements.

Sadly, it doesn't work. After trying to run:

```
int main() {
    std::set<std::vector<std::list<int>>> nested_ranges = {
            {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}},
            {{7},       {8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}},
            {{13}}
    };

    std::ranges::copy(
            rng::deep_flatten(nested_ranges),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
    );
}
```

I get an error saying that:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'auto rng::deep_flatten(Rng&&) [with Rng = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::set<std::vector<std::__cxx11::list<int> > > > >]':
>      required from 'auto rng::deep_flatten(Rng&&) [with Rng = std::set<std::vector<std::__cxx11::list<int> > >&]'
>      required from here
>      error: use of 'auto rng::deep_flatten(Rng&&) [with Rng = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::set<std::vector<std::__cxx11::list<int> > > > >]' before deduction of 'auto'
>      39 |             return deep_flatten(rng | views::join);
>         |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Having researched similar problems, I cannot really get why the error appears here.

I am using `gcc version 10.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first problem is yours:

```
namespace rng {
    template <std::ranges::range Rng>
    auto deep_flatten(Rng&& rng) {
        using namespace std::ranges;

        if constexpr (range<Rng>) { // <==
            return deep_flatten(rng | views::join);
        } else {
            return rng | views::join;
        }
    }
}
```

This function is infinitely recursive. `deep_flatten` is constrained `range<Rng>`, so the `if constexpr` check there is always going to be true, so we're never going to enter the base case. This is just a bug - we're checking the wrong thing, it's not if we're a range, it's if our underlying value is a range. That's:

```
namespace rng {
    template <typename Rng>
    auto deep_flatten(Rng&& rng) {
        using namespace std::ranges;

        auto joined = rng | views::join;    
        if constexpr (range<range_value_t<decltype(joined)>>) {
            return deep_flatten(joined);
        } else {
            return joined;
        }
    }
}
```

And here we get into the second problem, which is the standard library's problem. What `rng | views::join` means is:

> The name `views​::​join` denotes a range adaptor object ([range.adaptor.object]). Given a subexpression `E`, the expression `views​::​join(E)` is expression-equivalent to `join_­view{E}`.

But `join_view{E}` for an `E` that's already a specialization of `join_view`... is a no-op right now because of class template argument deduction (CTAD) - the copy deduction candidate is the best candidate, so our nested `join` operation actually becomes a single `join`. Your original implementation gets around this problem because it's not `join`-ing a `join_view`, it's always `join`-ing `vector`s.

I've submitted [LWG 3474](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3474).

In the meantime, we can work around the `views::join` problem by just directly using `join_view` and specifying the template argument explicitly:

```
namespace rng {
    template <typename Rng>
    auto deep_flatten(Rng&& rng) {
        using namespace std::ranges;


        auto joined = join_view<views::all_t<Rng>>(rng);

        if constexpr (range<range_value_t<decltype(joined)>>) {
            return deep_flatten(joined);
        } else {
            return joined;
        }
    }
}
```

This works.

Comment: Could you share the link to the LWG issue when you submit it? That would be really nice, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Barry. The first mistake was my oversight when I was refactoring the code - thank you nonetheless for pointing it out, since it will surely help me with noticing those things in the future. Regarding the second one, I'd like to second **cigien**'s comment - will you please share a link when you submit the issue?

Comment: OP problem does not seem *that* complicated so I would presume people thought of it during standardization. Are you sure this is a LWG issue, and not something that was decided to be not done?

Comment: @cigien Added link.

Comment: @Fureeish Added link

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl There is no way this is intentional behavior.

Comment: BTW, I used your solution, but I am having some performance issues... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74382366/why-is-iterating-over-stdrangesviewsjoin-so-slow