# C++20 Join the inner values of a map with value_type vector of vector using std::ranges

Tags: c++, range, c++20

Let's go for it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <map>

namespace rv = std::ranges::views;

int main()
{
    std::map<unsigned, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>>> m
        = {{0, {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}},
           {1, {{6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11}}}};
    
    for (unsigned u : m | rv::values | rv::join | rv::join)
        std::cout << u << ' ';
}
```

I want to print `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11`, but it fails to compile using `gcc 10.2.0`.

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges: In instantiation of 'constexpr const _Derived& std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::_M_derived() const [with _Derived = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >]':
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:130:73:   required from 'constexpr std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::operator bool() const requires requires{std::ranges::__cust::empty(((const std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>*)this)->std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::_M_derived()());} [with _Derived = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >]'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:2673:56:   required from 'constexpr auto std::ranges::join_view<_Vp>::end() [with _Vp = std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1>]'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:419:26:   required from 'constexpr auto std::ranges::__cust_access::_End::operator()(_Tp&&) const [with _Tp = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >&]'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:865:13:   required from 'constexpr auto std::ranges::views::__adaptor::operator|(_Range&&, const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure<_Callable>&) [with _Range = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >; _Callable = std::ranges::views::<lambda(_Range&&)>]'
main.cpp:15:55:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:112:16: error: static assertion failed
  112 |  static_assert(view<_Derived>);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:112:16: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/string:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:862:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'range<_Tp>' [with _Tp = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > > > > >, 1> >]
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:862:21:   in requirements with '_Tp& __t' [with _Tp = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > > > > >, 1> >]
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:865:13: note: the required expression 'std::ranges::__cust::end(__t)' is invalid
  865 |  ranges::end(__t);
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges: In instantiation of 'constexpr _Derived& std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::_M_derived() [with _Derived = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >]':
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:126:67:   required from 'constexpr std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::operator bool() requires requires{std::ranges::__cust::empty(((std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>*)this)->std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::_M_derived()());} [with _Derived = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >]'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:2673:56:   required from 'constexpr auto std::ranges::join_view<_Vp>::end() [with _Vp = std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1>]'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:419:26:   required from 'constexpr auto std::ranges::__cust_access::_End::operator()(_Tp&&) const [with _Tp = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >&]'
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:865:13:   required from 'constexpr auto std::ranges::views::__adaptor::operator|(_Range&&, const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure<_Callable>&) [with _Range = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > >, 1> >; _Callable = std::ranges::views::<lambda(_Range&&)>]'
main.cpp:15:55:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:105:16: error: static assertion failed
  105 |  static_assert(view<_Derived>);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ranges:105:16: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/string:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:862:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'range<_Tp>' [with _Tp = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > > > > >, 1> >]
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:862:21:   in requirements with '_Tp& __t' [with _Tp = std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > > > > >, 1> >]
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/range_access.h:865:13: note: the required expression 'std::ranges::__cust::end(__t)' is invalid
  865 |  ranges::end(__t);
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:15:55: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<unsigned int>' to 'unsigned int' in initialization
   15 |     for (unsigned u : m | rv::values | rv::join | rv::join)
```

Comment: Seems [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/j5n9e7) What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @cigien Question edited.

Comment: Ok, but this suggests it's just a compiler bug. What is your question exactly? Do you want a workaround for gcc10.2?

Comment: @cigien I will delete this question because I thought I was doing something wrong. But yes with an upgraded compiler it compiles fine as you have already proven.

Comment: This is [LWG 3474](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3474), submitted in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63249315/2069064).

Comment: Sorry, I closed this as a dupe, then reopened it because I got confused by the compile error you posted, but it should basically be that.

Comment: @Barry omg you posted that issue just a couple of days ago; it seems gcc has been very fast in solving it. Can we say that because of that premature fix gcc is not standard conforming right now? :P

Comment: @Barry Are you saying this is not supposed to work then?

Comment: @cigien I'm saying it _is_ supposed to work, but the version OP is using has the `join | join` part being a no-op (due to a library specification error), hence the error about trying to convert a `vector<unsigned int>` to `unsigned int` (last join didn't happen as expected)