# generic slicing (views) of multidimensional array in C++20 using ranges

Tags: c++, arrays, slice, c++20, std-ranges

In Python, accessing a subset of a multidimensional numpy is normally done using the slicing sintax [bx:ex] for a 1D array, [bx:ex,by:ey] for a 2D array and so on and so forth. It is also possible to write a code which is generic such as

```
def foo(Vin,Vout,lows,highs):
   # Vin and Vout are numpys with dimension len(lows)
   # and len(lows)=len(highs)
   
   S=tuple(slice(l,h) for l,h in zip(lows,highs))
   Vout[S]=Vin[S]
```

I would like to achieve something similar in C++, where the data is stored in a std::vector and having the same performance (or better) of a bunch of nested for-loops which for a 3D array would look like

```
for (int k=lz; k<hz; ++k)
    for (int j=ly; j<hy; ++j)
        for (int i=lx; i<hx; ++i)
             Vout[i+nx*(j+ny*k)=Vin[i+nx*(j+ny*k)];
```

Could this be done using C++20 ranges?
The long term goal is to generate lazily evaluated views of subsets of multidimensional arrays that can be combined together. In other words, being able to fuse loops without creating intermediate arrays.

Comment: What you need is C++23 `std::mdspan`.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself clearly. I do not want to write nested loops, because that would require to know when I write the code  the dimensionality of the vector (one for loop for each dimension). I would like to compose them just as I do in the example in Python. I could use macros to insert the right amount of for loops at compile time, but (a) I am not fond of macros, and (b) it still requires knowledge of the dimensionality at compile time, whereas a fully composable solution would work at run time.

Comment: It would be cool if `std::mdspan` had an overload of `operator[]` for `std::slice`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the performance, but here is one option.

You create a templated struct `MD<N,M,L>` that takes array dimensions `N,M,L` and has a static function `slice`.

`slice` takes a flat input range and one `Slice` instance per dimension and returns a corresponding multidimensional range over the elements of the flat input range.

The `Slice` instances are just structs containing a start index and an optional end index.

You can use `deep_flatten` from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250526/12173376) to prevent having to use nested for loops over the multidimensional range. Note that the returned range is just an `input_range`, which does not have a rich interface.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t dim>
struct Slice {
    // default constructor leaves start at zero and end empty. Correspondes to the whole dimension
    constexpr Slice() = default;

    // Create a slice with a single index
    constexpr Slice(size_t i) : begin(i), end(i+1) {
        assert( (0 <= i) && (i < dim));
    }

    // Create a slice with a start and an end index
    constexpr Slice(size_t s, size_t e) : begin(s), end(e+1) {
        assert( (0 <= s) && (s <= e) && (e < dim) );
    } 

    size_t begin {0};
    size_t end {dim};
};

// An adaptor object to interpret a flat range as a multidimensional array
template <size_t dim, size_t... dims>
struct MD {
    constexpr static auto dimensions = std::make_tuple(dim, dims...);
    consteval static size_t size(){
        if constexpr (sizeof...(dims) > 0) {
            return dim*(dims * ...);
        }
        else {
            return dim;
        }
    }

    // returns a multidimensional range over the elements in the flat array
    template <typename Rng>
    constexpr static auto slice(
        Rng&& range, 
        Slice<dim> const& slice, 
        Slice<dims> const&... slices
    )
    {        
        return slice_impl(range, 0, slice, slices...);
    }

    template <typename Rng>
    constexpr static auto slice_impl(
        Rng&& range, 
        size_t flat_index,  
        Slice<dim> const& slice, 
        Slice<dims> const&... slices
    )
    {
        if constexpr (std::ranges::sized_range<Rng>) { assert(std::size(range) >= size());  }
        static_assert(sizeof...(slices) == sizeof...(dims), "wrong number of slice arguments.");

        if constexpr (sizeof...(slices) == 0) 
        {
            // end recursion at inner most range
            return range | std::views::drop(flat_index*dim + slice.begin) | std::views::take(slice.end - slice.begin);
        }
        else 
        {
            // for every index to be kept in this dimension, recurse to the next dimension and increment the flat_index
            return std::views::iota(slice.begin, slice.end) | std::views::transform(
                [&range, flat_index, slices...](size_t i){
                    return MD<dims...>::slice_impl(range, flat_index*dim + i, slices...);
                }
            );
        }
    }

    // convenience function for the full view
    template <typename Rng>
    constexpr static auto as_range(Rng&& range){
        return slice(range, Slice<dim>{}, Slice<dims>{}...);
    }


};

// recursively join a range of ranges
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249315/use-of-auto-before-deduction-of-auto-with-recursive-concept-based-fun
template <typename Rng>
auto flat(Rng&& rng) {
    using namespace std::ranges;

    auto joined = rng | views::join;    
    if constexpr (range<range_value_t<decltype(joined)>>) {
        return flat(joined);
    } else {
        return joined;
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    static_assert(MD<2,3,2>::size() == 12);
    static_assert(std::get<0>(MD<2,3,2>::dimensions) == 2);
    static_assert(std::get<1>(MD<2,3,2>::dimensions) == 3);
    static_assert(std::get<0>(MD<2,3,2>::dimensions) == 2);

    std::vector v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

    // obtain the full view of the data, interpreted as a 2x3x2 array
    auto full = MD<2,3,2>::as_range(v);

    // print the full view
    std::cout << "data interpreted as 2x3x2 array:\n";
    for (size_t i=0; i < full.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "index " << i << ":\n";
        for (auto const& d3 : full[i]) {
            for (auto const& val : d3) {
                std::cout << val << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto sliced = MD<2,3,2>::slice(
        v, 
        {},    // 1st dim: take all elements along this dim
        {1,2}, // 2nd dim: take indices 1:2
        {0}    // 3rd dim: take only index 0
    );

    std::cout << "2x2x1 Slice with indices {{}, {1,2}, {0}} of the 2x3x2 data:\n";
    for(size_t i=0; i < 2; ++i){ // index-based loop
        for (size_t j=0; j < 2; ++j){
            std::cout << sliced[i][j][0] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for(auto& val : flat(sliced)){
        val  *= val;
    }

    // print the whole flat data
    std::cout << "\nThe whole data, after squaring all elements in sliced view:\n";
    for (auto const& val : v){
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
data interpreted as 2x3x2 array:
index 0:
1 2 
3 4 
5 6 
index 1:
7 8 
9 10 
11 12 

2x2x1 Slice with indices {{}, {1,2}, {0}} of the 2x3x2 data:
3 5 
9 11 


The whole data, after squaring all elements in sliced view:
1 2 9 4 25 6 7 8 81 10 121 12
```

[Live Demo on godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q1bnaG3Yo)

This is a prototype. I am sure the ergonomics can be improved.

### Edit

A first quick and dirty benchmark of assigning a 6x6x6 view with another 6x6x6 view out of a 10x10x10:

[image: Quickbench]
[Quickbench](https://quick-bench.com/q/3pRVt6t9wbvKsBn42o1J0x5cyvU)

A nested for loop over the multidimensional range is about 3 times slower than the traditional nested for-loop. Flattening the view using `deep_flatten`/`std::views::join` seems to make it 20-30 times slower. Apparently the compiler is having a hard time optimizing here.

Comment: I opened a SO question regarding about the poor performance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74382366/why-is-iterating-over-stdrangesviewsjoin-so-slow