# C++23 (or later) succinct way to extract elements of an array using an index vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, c++23, mdspan

I've been reviewing new ways of slicing arrays using the latest standards, but it's been a bit overwhelming and I have a question.

Is there any new, succinct way, with the new C++23 additions to `ranges`, `views`, `mdspan`, or even the ones to come `submdspan`, `mdarray`, to extract elements of an `mdspan` into another container using a vector with the indices to be extracted?

I have to work with `std::array` that I know their size beforehand, however, the indices will be known only at runtime so I can use temporary `std::vector` types or other containers.

Here's a godbolt [example](https://godbolt.org/z/67G998Px4), reproduced below

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kokkos/mdspan/single-header/mdspan.hpp>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t pDeg = 16 ;
    std::array<std::size_t,pDeg*pDeg> arr;
    for (std::size_t i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        arr[i] = i ;

    auto md = std::mdspan<std::size_t,std::extents<std::size_t,pDeg,pDeg>>(arr.data());

    std::vector<std::size_t> ind1 = {1,5,6,7,8,9,4,5};
    std::vector<std::size_t> ind2 = {14,11,12,13,11,1,5,6};

}
```

I have functions implemented to operate on matrices: `multiply()`, `add()`, etc

I would like to write matrix algebra expressions like

```
auto result = add(multiply(md[ind1,:],md[:,ind2]),md[ind1,ind2]);
```

where `md[ind1,:]` is a submatrix containing rows 1,5,6,7,8,9,4,5 of `md`, `md[:,ind2]` contains columns 14,11,12,13,11,1,5,6 of `md` and `md[ind1,ind2]` is a 8-by-8 submatrix of `md` containing all combinations of rows and columns given by `ind1` and `ind2` respectively (notice that indices can be repeated).

or something like

```
auto result = add(multiply(md.extract<0>(ind1),md.extract<1>(ind2)),md.extract<0,1>(ind1,ind2));
```

where `result` is always a `std::array` that I know the size at compile time.

The methods do not necessarily have to be the ones I propose, but they needs to be in a sort of short notation since there will be many matrix algebra operations.

Comment: Can you explain in your question what you're actually trying to do? I don't know what either `md[ind1, :]` or `md.extract<0>(ind1)` mean.

Comment: `mdarray` must wait till C++26 and `mdspan` is far from usable right now. Try avoiding them and there are `std::view` range-adapters + `std::ranges` algorithm for that matter. `ranges::copy(ranges::fold_left_first(views::zip_transform(multiplies<size_t>{}, r1, r2), plus<size_t>{}), begin(arr));`

Comment: @Barry Thank you. md[ind1,:] needs to extract a submatrix of md containing rows 1,5,6,7,8,9,4,5 (note that rows can be repeated). I need a succinct way to do it, even if it is different from the ones I propose.

Comment: `:` may be the Matlab notation for "all elements on this dimension" but you won't be able to use it that way in C++.  C++ operator overloading doesn't let you change the grammar, only the behavior.

Comment: Also `operator[]` only accepts one subscript.  You can get around that by passing a list: `md[{ind1, ind2}]`.

Comment: How do you know the size of result at compile time, if you don't know the indices at compile time?

Comment: Here is one solution that gives you views into your `mdspan`: https://godbolt.org/z/ej5Mdrcsd. You call it like this: `peek(arr2)(ind1, ind2)` or `peek(arr2)(ind1, all{})`, where the tag `all` is used in place of the `:` to refer to all indices along this dimension. I am too ashamed to post this as an answer though, because the code is hardly legible and I have reservations about the performance...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031279/generic-slicing-views-of-multidimensional-array-in-c20-using-ranges/74344108#74344108

Comment: @joergbrech Thank you so much! This gives me a better idea on how ranges and views work. I have to see how can I get the output to be another mdspan or submdspan though, because I need to do more algebraic operations with these matrices. I don't know the sizes of the members of the operations because they are randomized compressed and their rank is unknown at compile time, but I do know what the final, not compressed operator is.